# How to set alternate background color for tableview cell with sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use below code for setting background color in cells

```
if (indexPath.item % 2) {
    // odd
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
} else {
    // even
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

This works ok if section has even number of rows, but if odd then two adjoining cells have the same color ( I have several setions).

I have no idea how to correct this.

Comment: (sum of number of rows in previous sections + row number in section) % 2

Comment: Testing indexPath.row%2 == 0 seems to work for me when checking if even

Comment: If this is for a table view, you can't use `indexPath.item`. Did you mean `indexPath.row` in your question?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can also use this

```
static BOOL isEven = YES;

if(isEven) {
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
else {
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

isEven = !isEven;

Comment: This will lead to unexpected issues. `static` variables are static to all the program. Plus, you can't expect `cellForRow:` to be called sequentially on every rows of the table (ie `cellForRow` could be called for row 4 before row 3).

Answer (score 1):

Try with indexPath.row:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    // odd
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
} else {
    // even
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAt simply call one line:

```
cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? .blue : .white
```

hope this help :)